# Find tuples in a list of tuples, with consecutive values and turn them into bigger tuples

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples, each having two elements. Example:

```
my_tuples = [('black', 'grey'), ('red', 'orange'), ('blue', 'purple'), 
             ('orange', 'yellow'), ('grey', 'white'), ('yellow', 'cream')]
```

I am looking for an efficient way to find all the tuples whose first values are identical to second value of another one, make a triple of them, and continue adding values in this manner until all such chains are found. In this example, it should give the following list back:

```
my_tuples_processed = [('black', 'grey', 'white'), ('blue', 'purple'), 
                       ('red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'cream')]
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: What if there, for example, are two tuples starting with "white"? Which one should be concatenated with the one ending in "white"?

Comment: It it exists, then the function should return an error. Such a case is not among the fesaible scenarios for this problem.

Comment: What about two tuples *ending* with the same color?

Comment: How efficient does it need to be? There aren't that many color names, so I imagine every way will be fast.

Comment: What have you tried yourself this far? How much too inefficient was your solution?

Comment: In the datasets I have, such cases won't happen. And I mentioned colors here simply as examples. In reality, it can be tuples of integers, or any arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a dictionary to efficiently find the starting values and the connections, and using lists to efficiently concatenate the values ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDBjoMgEIbvPMXcgKTby142Jj7JxjRUptWUCkHcytPbAa1rE5NyAf75/@FjXAyN7b5/nJ@mezyFwRnsoYRfwc9G1Td@AH71GLk8gOAedRKsV90VZ@lsBkyaGzxFk8Zgu8TLTZ6IxtjHnMtNSXs0bVhaLWUSa4/qzmXFcHRYhz2e9@gnii3P@yf@sbbvsnUWJ@dtjX2POlFULG26rYNYHZJdrIcR2g708YaxFxK@6PinCIouRUZxKjSpw1jlK7EbXELFyppMR@UcdlqMUNBL5Je5vAP0cmZdpKyUjDnfdkH01gfUYidFno8WKEuYRy@n6Qk)):

```
my_tuples_processed = []
d = dict(my_tuples)
for x in d.keys() - d.values():
    path = [x]
    while x in d:
        path.append(x := d[x])
    my_tuples_processed.append(tuple(path))
```

This assumes that no value appears twice as first or twice as second value (as discussed in the question's comments).

An iterator alternative mostly because I love iterators ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVFBbsMgELzzir0ZKieXXqpI/kI/UEURNhvbCgG04Aa/3gU7SR3JUrgAszOzs@DG0Fnz@eVomq7jKQxOo4cKfnhRa9lcihKKlnAsRAm8IFQZsCRNiwtU6wEz5gZK0owxWC/@YCfOiFrb26KbTRN26/pwt7qXE9gQymshjgyjwyZs5XmVvkuxzvM6xH@sdV/2fIuTI9ug96hyiiPLm@qbwJ8MwRSeocXAxWHu2mpbSw1xvhCGgQzwCIck3GdaFIKdLUGE3iTogqPnAnbp@CvTHP7h42ToUrdYwkcalHjSlvBtDYq5vBFxL51Do3hWCsYc9SZwbymg4hv0lOMtBaoKll8Q0/QH)):

```
my_tuples_processed = []
d = dict(my_tuples)
def get():
    global x
    return (x := d.get(x))
for x in d.keys() - d.values():
    path = x, *iter(get, None)
    my_tuples_processed.append(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I add my own original solution before posting this question, simply for the sake of completelness. But it is not really an efficient solution and the accepted answer is much preferable.

```
def sort_merge_tuples(list_tuples):
    my_tuples = list_tuples.copy()
    cc1 = 0
    while cc1 < len(my_tuples):
        my_t = my_tuples[cc1]
        cc2 = 0
        while cc2 < len(my_tuples):
            my_t2 = my_tuples[cc2]
            if my_t[-1] == my_t2[0]:
                new_tuple = my_t + my_t2[1:]
                my_tuples.remove(my_t)
                my_tuples.remove(my_t2)
                my_tuples.append(new_tuple)
                cc1 = 0
                break
            elif my_t2[-1] == my_t[0]:
                new_tuple = my_t2 + my_t[1:]
                my_tuples.remove(my_t)
                my_tuples.remove(my_t2)
                my_tuples.append(new_tuple)
                cc1 = 0
                break
            cc2 = cc2 + 1
        cc1 = cc1 + 1
    return my_tuples
```